# How to convert NSData to a C struct and use it in Swift program

Tags: swift, struct, nsdata

the data should be binary data, it came from a 360 camera with bluetooth or wifi link ,it will call the function when data is prepared

`//ins_gyro_info binary @property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSData *gyroData;`

```
struct ins_gyro_info {   
    int64_t timestamp;   //millisecond   
    double gravity_x;   
    double gravity_y;   
    double gravity_z;   
    double rotation_x;   
    double rotation_y;   
    double rotation_z; 
};
```

`- (void)rawDataOutput:(INSCameraRawDataOutput *)rawDataOutput didOutputGyro:(NSData *)gyroData timestamp:(int64_t)timestamp;`

and I wanna use this gyro info in my Swift program, the function in Swift like below

`func rawDataOutput(_ rawDataOutput: INSCameraRawDataOutput, didOutputGyro gyroData: Data, timestamp: Int64)`

I am hard to try stuff the data into ins_gyro_info

Comment: Well, what format is the data in? Is it the same format as the struct layout?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.